# Change default URL of image attachment

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, attachments, images

*I have only one image attachment per post, as featured image. Every post have just one image, featured image, and no any other image in post content.*

By default URL of image attachment is:

```
http://www.my-site.com/category/sub-category/article-name/attachment/attachment-title
```

How to change it to this?

```
http://www.sitename.com/category/sub-category/article-name/image
```

or

```
http://www.sitename.com/category/sub-category/article-name/hd
```

or just

```
http://www.my-site.com/category/sub-category/article-name/attachment
```

(Without image title at the end of url)

---

**Usage:**

I have site, image gallery, and I wish to move it from current CMS to WordPress. On old CMS I have one page with medium image on it, and one more page with same image in high resolution on it.

I will redirect old page URL with medium image on it to post URL on WordPress:

```
http://www.my-site.com/category/sub-category/article-name/attachment/attachment-title
```

Old page with full size image on it I will redirect on that shorter attachment URL. It will be much better that attachment URL is shorter, and easier for making 301 redirection, like this:

```
http://www.sitename.com/category/sub-category/article-name/image
or
http://www.sitename.com/category/sub-category/article-name/hd
```

Comment: Can I ask why you're trying to do this? What is the purpose?

Comment: I am moving site (image gallery) from old CMS to WordPress. On old CMS I have one page with medium image on it, and one more page with image in high resolution on it. I will redirect old page URL with medium image on it to post URL on WP, and old page with full size image on it I will redirect on that shorter attachment URL. It will be much better that attachment URL is shorter, and easier for making 301 redirection.

Comment: If you have any more question, do not hesitate to ask. Thank you.

Comment: I revised my question, any ideas @tomjnowell?