# Show post tags on attachment page?

Tags: tags, attachments

I use this code to show post tag(s) on single.php template:

```
<?php the_tags('<div>Tagged with:<br> ',' | ','</div>');?>
```

I wish to display post tags on attachment page too, but code above shows nothing on attachment (image.php) template.

How to display parent post tag(s) on attachment page (specially on attachment page of post featured image)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work to get the parent's tags.

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$attachment_id = $wp_query->post->ID;
$parent_id = get_post_field('post_parent', $attachment_id);
$parent_tags = wp_get_post_tags($parent_id); 
$tag_count = count($parent_tags); // Counting the tags to find know the last one so there is no pipe
$i = 1; // Setting up the count

if ($parent_tags) { ?>
    <div>
    Tagged with:<br />
    <?php foreach ($parent_tags as $tag) {
        if($i < $tag_count) {
            echo '<a href=' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '>' . $tag->name . '</a> | ';
        } else {
            echo '<a href=' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '>' . $tag->name . '</a>';  
        }
        $i++;
    } ?>
    </div>
} ?>
```

Comment: Thank you again @kel, maybe you will have time to see my other unanswered questions: [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173143/changing-attachment-url] and [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/171995/change-default-url-of-image-attachment].

Comment: Is there any way to check if there is any tag first, because it display: '<div>
Tagged with:<br />
</div>'  even if there is no tag on post?

Comment: Yes, I've modified my code above so it will only show if there are tags.

Answer (score 0):

Attachments are a separate post type in WordPress, so on theory if you want to specify tags for each uploaded file, you'll have to use this in your active theme's functions.php:

```
register_taxonomy( 'post_tag', 'attachment', $args );
```

For $args have a look here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Comment: I do not wish to "_...specify tags for each uploaded file..._". I wish to display tags of parrent post on attachment page (attachment page of post featured image).

Comment: Sorry, seems I got it all wrong there :)